# Access Visual C++ DLL from Python (__thiscall calling convention)

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to access a class in a closed-source DLL from Python, compiled with Visual C++.
I have no header files, just the object code and no interface descriptions.

I can load the DLL using `ctypes.CDLL`, but any attempt to call a function results in an access violation. Apparently ctypes doesn't know about the `__thiscall` calling convention (it's not designed for C++ anyway). Usually, I'd simply write an extension module, but without source code I'm out of luck here.

This is what MSDN says:

> The __thiscall calling convention is used on member functions and is
>   the default calling convention used by C++ member functions that do
>   not use variable arguments. Under __thiscall, the callee cleans the
>   stack, which is impossible for vararg functions. Arguments are pushed
>   on the stack from right to left, with the this pointer being passed
>   via register ECX, and not on the stack, on the x86 architecture.

For example, this is how the exported function signature looks (unmangled):

`public: __thiscall CFoo::CFoo(void)`

My attempt to access the constructor from Python:

```
getattr(dll, "??0CFoo@@QAE@XZ")(c_voidp())
```

This doesn't work because ctypes doesn't pass the instance pointer, and all I get is an access violation.

I guess that I can't easily do this because ctypes has no C++ support, and as every compiler has its own name mangling conventions, it would be difficult to implement it in a generic way. The `__thiscall` calling convention is not implemented by ctypes.

The obvious workaround would be a wrapper, written in Visual C++, which exports the function as `__stdcall`, but I don't want to rely on this.

Correct? Or is there any trick I missed?

Comment: No, unless something changed recently in ctypes, it indeed does not support C++. http://stackoverflow.com/a/145649/477878 has a workaround, but may be tedious if you don't have the original headers.

Comment: Have you looked at [Cython](http://www.cython.org/)? I feel pretty confident it can link statically with a C++ library.

Comment: Yes, I do a lot of work in Cython, but without header files, this seems rather difficult.

Comment: Cant you look up the address of the function through os apis and then cast it to a function pointer? Im not quite sure how __thiscall behaves on constructors but if am i right youll have to pass it a fresh allocated memory block of the objects size.

Comment: @leoluk You don't actually need header files (though I don't know how they expect anyone to use it without a header file), any API reference will do. If you have an API reference, you can write your own header file that will just implement the parts you need.

Comment: @Josiah In case certain members are unknown one can insert placeholders like `unsigned char unk1[16]` guranteing that known members after this unknown region can be accessed normally.

Comment: They did not expect anyone to use it, this is the problem (complete lack of documentation), and the company vanished. The DLL controls video capture hardware using a strange UDP protocol (hard to reverse-engineer), and I want to implement my own client.

Comment: Apparently, [this patch](https://code.google.com/p/ctypes-stuff/source/browse/trunk/ctypes-cpp/README) adds support for `__thiscall` to ctypes. This might be exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: If you know how to call the functions and what they return, you know all you need to make a small header file to use for a Cython extension.